# Does every RCTRootView have its own javascript context?

Tags: react-native

If we create multiple RCTRootViews in a single react native application and have them load different javascript bundles, are they going to be run in completely isolated contexts? Completely sandboxed and no conflicts at all?

Answer (score 1):

If the bundles are using separate *bridges*, then you are effectively creating multiple react native applications running at once. Therefore, they will indeed be 'sandboxed' with no conflicts.

However, it is also possible to load different bundles using the same *bridge*, in which case the different bundles are used in one single react native application and they can communicate with each other.